# jQuery Code Completion in Netbeans for *.js Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, netbeans-7, code-completion

Im using NetBeans 7.1.2 and jQuery 1.7.2

I can use codecompletion in HTML and PHP Files, but not in external JS Files.
Both Files are included in index.php File.

```
<script src="js/demo.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```

In the index.php the jQuery CodeCompletion is avaible in script.
In the demo.js not.

How can i use the CodeCompletion in the demo.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

1. Downloading the developer version of jquery
2. Include the jquery file in js/jquery-Version.js
3. Adjust the BrowserSupportSettings in Options->Misc